# Couchbase - querying a reduced view with a compound key using a specific key

Tags: couchbase

I'm trying to get the last 10 transactions for a specific user.

For example, I have these documents:

```
{ "user": 1, "date": 1442408126 }
{ "user": 1, "date": 1442408130 }
{ "user": 1, "date": 1442408140 }
{ "user": 2, "date": 1442408126 }
```

And I defined this view:

```
// MAP:
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
    if(doc.user && doc.date) {  
      var eventKey = dateToArray(new Date(parseInt(doc.date)));
      eventKey.unshift(doc.user);

      emit(eventKey, {"date":doc.date});
    }
  }
}

// REDUCE:
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  return values.slice(0,10);
}
```

When `reduce=true` and `group_level=1`, this is the result (which is good):

```
Key    Value
[1]    [ { "date": 1442408140 }, { "date": 1442408130 }, { "date": 1442...
[2]    [ { "date": 1442408126 } ]
```

now, when I query the view with `startKey=[1]` and `endKey=[2]` *(stale=false&startkey=%5B1%5D&endkey=%5B2%5D&group=true&group_level=1&reduce=true&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0)*, I get the row that I want:

```
Key    Value
[1]    [ { "date": 1442408140 }, { "date": 1442408130 }, { "date": 1442...
```

**BUT**, I want to use key=[1] and not do a range search.

When I use the key parameter *(stale=false&group=true&group_level=1&key=%5B1%5D&reduce=true&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0)*, I get an empty result.

Using `startKey=[1]` and `endKey=[1]` with inclusive_end=true also returns an empty list.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using the key parameter? By querying the view with startKey[1] ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use "key=[1]", but I don't mind any solution that allows me to query by a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

For Couchbase, believe there is a built-in _count function that automatically handles the rereduce so that you get a count of all items in a result set, not the count of the reduced set.

Can reference the [Reduce Functions](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-writing.html#reduce-functions) on the documentation page.

Comment: I'm not getting items count, but the items themselves. Actually my problem is not with the reduce function, but with querying by a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer: when using a view with a complex key, one cannot use the 'key' parameter in a query. In this case we have to use startKey and endKey while the endKey is the same as the startKey but with an addition of an empty object at the end. For example startKey=[1], endKey=[1,{}]

More details here: http://ryankirkman.com/2011/03/30/advanced-filtering-with-couchdb-views.html